# Dump Banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, dump

Tem alguma forma de saber se foi ou quando foi realizado um ***DUMP*** de um banco de dados?

Comment: Talvez seria interessante realizar backups constantes do DB

Comment: Mas tem como ver que foi realizado um backup?

Comment: Seria interessante saber qual o banco você usa e qual ferramenta de acesso.

Answer (score 2):

Faça um `SELECT` na tabela `backupset`:

```
SELECT b.database_name AS base,
       CASE b.type
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'Completo'
            WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diferencial'
            ELSE 'Outro'
        END tipo,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.backup_finish_date, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.backup_finish_date, 108) AS fim
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset b
 ORDER BY b.database_name, b.backup_finish_date DESC
```

> [**`backupset`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186299(v=sql.110).aspx)
>
> Contém uma linha para cada conjunto de backup. Um conjunto de backup contém o backup de uma única operação de backup bem-sucedida.